# How to specify the generics when using Flux.handle()

Tags: java, project-reactor

As title, I don't know how to specify the generics when I using `Flux.handle()`.
It will return a `Flux<Object>` after the `handle()` method like below example.

```
Flux.range(0, 10) // 1
        .handle((x, sink) -> {
            if (x % 2 == 0)
                sink.next(x);
        }) // 2
        .map(o -> Integer.valueOf(o.toString()))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

It's a simple example to express the problem I'm facing so please don't care whether the content could be better.

The IDE shows `Flux<Integer>` at 1 and `Flux<Object>` at 2, so I need to add a `map()` method to transform the type which I want to use.

Is there any way to specify the return type without using `map()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a type witness:

```
Flux.range(0, 10)
    .<Integer>handle((x, sink) -> {
        if (x % 2 == 0)
            sink.next(x);
    });
```

This resolves to `Flux<Integer>`

This is a deficiency in Java's type inference, rather than a specific flaw of this class. Type witnesses are Java's way of explicitly declaring the generic type parameters, rather than relying on them being inferred.

Comment: It's very thanks for your answer!